# How does a scheduler end a running process?

Tags: scheduling, cpu

I just realized that after learning a lot about various scheduling algorithms, how a context switch is done, etc. one thing still isn't clear to me.

Take a uniprocessor system:

If process `A` is running and it's time slot should end in 5 seconds, how does the scheduler or the operating system know how to end it after 5 seconds?  No part of the operating system can run while A is running.  The scheduler is supposed to be monitoring it, but how can it if it cannot run?  Does the operating system's scheduler write an ISR and have an interrupt generate every 5 seconds?  Is this possible?  Even if it is, it doesn't seem a good way to implement it.

How exactly does a scheduler do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the operating system's scheduler write an ISR and have an interrupt generate every 5 seconds? Is this possible? Even if it is, it doesn't seem a good way to implement it.

Yes, this is exactly how it works on a preemptive multitasking system (although on desktop systems the interval is usually more like 10 milliseconds).

Yes, there are other schemes, such as cooperative multitasking, where each process decides for itself when to yield.

Comment: How exactly does it generate an interrupt every X ms?

Comment: @Vanwaril, with some sort of timer.  Obviously it depends on the ISA.  Here's one way to do it.  Have a CPU register that triggers an interrupt when its value reaches 0.  The operating system writes to the register, perhaps the value 10 milliseconds * 2 GHz = 20 million.  The counter is decremented every clock cycle, and after 20 million clock cycles an interrupt is triggered, and the operating system's ISR runs and performs scheduling logic.

Comment: @rlibby, Could you please suggest some books/online resources which discusses this concept more broadly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, normally there is some kind of timer interrupt that fires.  The kernel can then run for a bit and switch process context if it needs to - normally that interrupt would fire an awful lot more often than just once every 5 seconds though.  Why doesn't it seem like a good way to implement it?

Comment: Because it would have to fire very very often.  If it fires every 20ms or so just to handle new processes/see whether the current process can continue, its time slice is up, or it should be pre-empted, then doesn't that eat up a lot of your CPU time? and I thought current OS's use 20ms time slots, so wouldn't this have to fire much more often?

Comment: @Vanwaril, yes, it eats some time, but as long as the interrupt handler is much shorter than the time slice, it doesn't eat *that much* time.  20 ms may seem like a very short time to you, but to a 2 GHz CPU, it's 40 million cycles.  The bigger cost of context switching is not the time lost, but the cache lost.